# У меня есть 5 таблиц с разными жанрами фильмов. Почему при вводе имени в поиск находит только из последней таблице

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb", 'root','');

if ( isset($_POST["submit-search"]) )
{
    $str = $_POST["search-bar"];
    
    $sth = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM horror WHERE NameArtist = '$str'");
    $sth = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM comeny WHERE NameArtist = '$str'");
    $sth = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM action WHERE NameArtist = '$str'");
    $sth = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM fantasy WHERE NameArtist = '$str'");
    $sth = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM adventure WHERE NameArtist = '$str'");
    $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $sth-> execute();

    if($row = $sth->fetch())
    {
        ?>
        <br><br><br>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row->NameArtist. " - "; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->NameFilm; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Name does  not exist";
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: Только имя в adventure ищет, а во всех остальных нет.
Как это исправить?

Comment: Для начала, pdo так не юзают -> `WHERE NameArtist = '$str'"`. Вам надо для каждой таблицы делать execute и собирать данные в массив. А так-то странная у вас структура - по таблице на жанр...

Comment: Задание просто такое с 5 таблицами на жанр)

Comment: База данных в задании спроектирована прямо скажем через опу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете попробовать объединить все запросы с помощью UNION:
http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/UNION.html

```
$sth = $connection->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM horror WHERE NameArtist = '$str' 
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM comeny WHERE NameArtist = '$str'
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM action WHERE NameArtist = '$str'
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM fantasy WHERE NameArtist = '$str' 
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM adventure WHERE NameArtist = '$str'
");
```

Comment: Спасибо!
ОНО ЖИВОЕ))