# PHP поиск данных

Tags: php, mysql

помогите пожалуйста!
Как сделать поиск из двух и более таблиц таблиц ?
У меня есть одна таблица 'rock' а так же есть таблица 'jazz', я хочу что бы поиск данных ввёлся не только из одно, а из двух.

```
 <?php
            $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '','musicartistdata');
            if(isset($_POST['search-bar']))
            {
               $searchkey = $_POST['search-bar'];
               $sql = "SELECT * FROM rock WHERE NameArtist LIKE '%$searchkey%'";
            }
            else
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM rock";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        ?>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>NameArtist</th>
                <th>NameSong</th>
            </tr>
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row->NameArtist ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->NameSong ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: Вы там не из одной группы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1144802/%d0%a3-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86-%d1%81-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bd

Comment: не надо делать отдельные таблицы для разных жанров. Сделайте таблицу жанры, где будет 1 - rock, 2 - jazz и т.п. и таблицу с артистами или что там у вас где будет bon jovi - стиль 1 и т.п. хотя учитывая, что одни и те же исполнители играют во многих стилях, понадобится скорее всего третя таблица, где будут жанры исполнителя. Тогда артист(группа) скажем F.P.G id=10, и в таблице стилей (10, 1), (10,2) и рок и джаз